# Execute insert query from stored procedure result set based on output parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored procedure which returns a resultset (a select statement) and a output parameter say `@IsError`. ResultSet is only being return when `@IsError` is set to 1.

Now I am calling this procedure from another procedure and want to insert the data return from this procedure only when `@IsError` is 1.

```
INSERT INTO #Order_Error(col1, col2, col3)
EXEC myStoredProc @param1, @param2, @IsError output
```

I want to put the check that data should only be insert in `#Order_Error` if out param i.e. `@IsError` is 1.

For the reference here is the `myStoredProc` definition.

```
CREATE PROC myStoreProc
(   @param1 int,
    @param2 varchar(50),
    @IsError bit output
)
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        -- My T-SQL operations like insert or update to the table. Nothing returns from this block i.e. No SELECT statement.
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure, ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    SET @IsError = 1
    END CATCH
END
```

I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: can you provide `myStoredProc `  ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I added the definition.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you want to insert data in #Order_Error table if 'myStoreProc' stored procedure sets @IsError = 1. 
Do you have a separate stored procedure to insert data in #Order_Error table or just a Insert statement?

Comment: @Himanshugaur, yes you are right and it just a insert statement, no separate procedure to insert the data into #Order_Error table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update CATCH statement in your stored procedure to include INSERT statement:

```
CREATE PROC myStoreProc
(   @param1 int,
    @param2 varchar(50),
    @IsError bit output
)
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        -- My T-SQL operations like insert or update to the table. Nothing returns from this block i.e. No SELECT statement.
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure, ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    SET @IsError = 1
    IF (@IsError = 1)
    BEGIN
           <INSERT statement for #Order_Error>
    END
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this is one go. But you can use staging table like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
@IsError BIT OUTPUT
AS

SET @IsError = 1
SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B
GO


DECLARE @IsError BIT

CREATE TABLE #Final(A INT, B INT)
CREATE TABLE #Staging(A INT, B INT)

INSERT INTO #Staging
EXEC spTest @IsError OUTPUT


IF @IsError = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Final
    SELECT * FROM #Staging
END


SELECT * FROM #Final


DROP TABLE #Final
DROP TABLE #Staging
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE spTest
@IsError BIT OUTPUT
AS

SET @IsError = 0
SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B
GO


DECLARE @IsError BIT

CREATE TABLE #Final(A INT, B INT)
CREATE TABLE #Staging(A INT, B INT)

INSERT INTO #Staging
EXEC spTest @IsError OUTPUT


IF @IsError = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Final
    SELECT * FROM #Staging
END


SELECT * FROM #Final


DROP TABLE #Final
DROP TABLE #Staging
GO
```

Output1:

```
A   B
1   2
```

Output2:

```
A   B
```

Another way is to use temp table inside the second stored procedure as it will see the temp table created from outside as:

> If you create a temporary table in one stored procedure—for example,
>   call it Proc1— that temporary table is visible to all other stored
>   procedures called from Proc1. However, that temporary table is not
>   visible to any procedures that call Proc1.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
@IsError BIT OUTPUT
AS

SET @IsError = 1

INSERT INTO #Final
SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B
GO


DECLARE @IsError BIT

CREATE TABLE #Final(A INT, B INT)

EXEC spTest @IsError OUTPUT


SELECT * FROM #Final
```

Comment: In your first approach, if `@IsError` is set to 0, data is returning but in my case when `@IsError` is 0 nothing will be returned from the stored procedure. It only returns in case of `@IsError` = 1. See my procedure definition.

Comment: @Sachin, it doesn't matter. You will have to insert into staging table anyway(in first case some rows, in second case you will insert no rows).